# Color area of a closed shape formed by ones in binary matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

I am trying to solve following problem:
Suppose we have a binary matrix for example:

```
000100
001010
010001
001010
000100
```

So,how can I fill the area within the closed shape with ones?
And first, how can I determine that the shape is closed?

Comment: Using connected components, you can create different closed shapes.

Comment: One solution is a flood fill: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill